# Cisco Visio Nexus Stencils (Purple)

Tags: cisco

Anyone know where I can download the newer purple-hued Nexus series switch stencils that are commonly used in Cisco presentations?  I'm looking for Visio format (.vss)

I'm **not** referring to the Physical view stencils that are available @ http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/prod_cat_visios.html

I am looking for the logical stencils.

Thanks!